# Howto use WWW::Mechanize to access pages split by drop-down list

Tags: javascript, html, perl, unix, mechanize

I have list of genes to download from the following links.
the problem that it's separated into 60 pages, under the drop-down list.

```
http://diana.cslab.ece.ntua.gr/micro-CDS/index.php?r=search/results_mature&mir=hsa-miR-3131&kwd=MIMAT0014996
```

How can I make [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) access all the genes from all the pages?

This is the current code I have:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $url = "http://diana.cslab.ece.ntua.gr/micro-CDS/index.php?r=search/results_mature&mir=hsa-miR-3131&kwd=MIMAT0014996";

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->agent_alias("Windows IE 6");

$mech->get($url);
#only access the first page.
```

Comment: WWW::Mechanize doesn't do Javascript. See http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FAQ.pod#JavaScript

Comment: Are you sure the site doesn't have an API, so you don't have to scrape this stuff from an interactive web page?

Answer (score 1):

The page drop-down is implemented using Javascript. You can't do this with Mechanize, because it doesn't implement Javascript. See the [FAQ](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FAQ.pod#JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

This is easy -- the page number is inside URL (this is for page #11):

```
my $page_number = 11;
$mech->get( "http://diana.cslab.ece.ntua.gr/micro-CDS/index.php?r=search%2Finitializesearch&keywords=MIMAT0014996&thr=0.41&kegg=&page=" . $page_number );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$pages = 60;
for($i=1;$pages<=60;$i++){
    $url = "http://diana.cslab.ece.ntua.gr/micro-CDS/index.php?r=search%2Finitializesearch&keywords=MIMAT0014996&thr=0.41&kegg=&page=$i"
    $mech->get($url);
}
```

This should do it. You just need to iterate through the 60 pages, modifying the URL each time.